# Linux: Does find | xargs grep have limitations?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find, xargs

I've historically performed something like:

```
find . 2>/dev/null | xargs grep -i something_to_find 2>/dev/null
```

If my `pwd` is barfoo (`/foo/bar/baz/foofoo/foobar/foobaz/barfoo`) it finds matches.  However, if I `cd` to `/foo`, it no longer finds the matches.

---

Conditions:

- permissions are all 775
- the directories are not symbolic links
- they are all on the same file system / server

---

So I'm curious if there is a default `-maxdepth` that is applied to find, or are there other constraints as to why this would not work?

---

#### Additional Info:

Some great comments have been posted.  Here is some additional info:

- this is for GNU, not POSIX
- `find --version` : GNU find version 4.2.27
- `grep --version` : (GNU grep) 2.5.1
- `xargs --version` : GNU xargs version 4.2.27
- removing the redirection of STDERR has no bearing on the result, or lack thereof
- the path to the files in `barfoo` (known to work) do not have spaces, however files in other directories in `/foo/bar` may have spaces; though, I don't see how that would be problematic
- I realize I wasn't specific on the path, but these are all well-named directories, not to be confused with any devices

#### Interesting Finding:

The first doesn't work, but the second does:

1. `find . -type f                | xargs grep -i something_to_find`
2. `find . -type f -name "*.ext"  | xargs grep -i something_to_find`

Even odder is that `-name "*.*"` does not work, the file extension has to be given; which could be problematic when searching for something.

I'm wondering if there is termination after a max error count, or maximum buffer size.  I know there are a lot of files in these directories, but the fact it works when specifying the filetype (limiting results) is interesting.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that by deliberately redirecting stderr to the bit bucket, you may be hiding a useful error message from yourself,

Comment: @rici: I've removed both error redirections and the only errors that appear are `Permission denied` or `No such file or directory`, which I don't see applying to the path above.  I've also tried `-type f` for the find to simplify the search

Comment: By any chance, does `something_to_find` have slashes, a caret, or a dollar sign in it?

Comment: @wallyk Why would that matter?

Comment: If you replace `xargs grep ...` with `wc -l`, do you get the same or different results in the two cases?

Comment: @Barmar:  If searching for `barfoo` using the expression `^barfoo` it might work in one situation but not the other.

Comment: Have you tried to step upward one dir each time (cd .. ; find ...)? At what directory does it happen then?

Comment: @wallyk The files searched in the first case are a subset of the files in the second case. So any matches from the first case should be found in the second, regardless of the regexp.

Comment: I don't think there's a default `-maxdepth`, but there could be a filesystem limit on the length of pathnames. How long are the real pathnames involved?

Comment: Your paths don't have spaces in them by any chance?

Comment: Since you mention "same server":  Is there any chance that special files like /proc/kcore or /dev/zero are anywhere in the path?  That would certainly stop grep from going any further.....

Comment: As @rici mentions, check for path names with spaces, but also look for symbolic links that `cd` would traverse, but `find` won't by default.

Comment: someone else posted this problem in the last 2-3 days. Sorry don't have time to search for it. Might help to add `uname` and `find --version ; xargs --version ;grep --version` output to your posting. (But I'm guessing spaces in path names). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I didn't see that, could you post a link

Comment: Remove the `2>/dev/null` if you want to have any chance of finding out what's going on. Edit your question to add the error messages.

Comment: For future reference, you should use `grep`'s `-r` option to search recursively.  `grep -ir find_this .`

Comment: @Gilles: before I post a question, I try many options.  In this particular instance it had no bearing on the outcome, so I included the version as part of the question

Comment: @Kevin: I'm not sure what that would buy me.  `find` is supplying all the files, so `grep` shouldn't also need to read each file twice; unless, I'm not understanding the recursive nature of grep

Comment: `grep -r` would save at least two processes, probably more, depending on the number of files and folders you have and their names. And a fair bit of string parsing. And why would it read each file twice? It gets a name, if it's a folder it recurses and if not it reads it.

Comment: @Kevin: I think I misunderstood you.  Were you talking about using grep as a standalone instead of piping find's output to it?

Comment: Yes, just `grep`. No `find`, no `xcode`

Comment: @Kevin: then that makes sense (thank you), I was talking about the combination of them both, which I don't know how it'd work, but I imagine it could check the same file exponentially

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directories with names that contain spaces, visible from `/foo/bar` and not from `barfoo`, are the likely culprits. `xargs` splits its output by spaces, and also interprets quotes, backslashes, and even the `_` character—see [the manual](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xargs.htm) for details, so whitespace in file or directory names cause it to pass incomplete file names to `grep`.

To work around this issue, use `find -print0` in conjunction with `xargs -0`, like this:

```
find . -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 grep -i something_to_find 2>/dev/null
```

The `-print0` option tells `find` to separate file names with a binary 0 character, which cannot appear in a valid file name. The corresponding `-0` option tells part to use that same character as the separator, and also not to interpret quotes and backslashes.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense.  What I don't completely understand is why it would crash, and not continue on, even if it encountered a file that didn't exist.  Regardless, this solved my particular issue +5 (if i could)

Comment: Maybe it's not the spaces, `xargs` could also have encountered an apostrophe in file name (often present in file names of songs or films), which would make it search for a "matching quote", nowhere to be found. Since you completely discard error output, you wouldn't have seen the "unmatched single quote" error, nor errors from `grep`. When debugging problems, it's a good idea to at least temporarily remove the `2>/dev/null` redirections, so programs can warn you of mistakes.

Comment: When I debugged, I removed the error redirection (`removing the redirection of STDERR has no bearing on the result, or lack thereof`) and I didn't notice anything other than permission denied/does not exist errors (no special characters).  I think the does not exist errors were because of the spaces, but it encountered a few of those and still continued on.  I'm still stumped on what the true nature was, but am appreciative of your help.  I think I tried the `-0` on xargs, but didn't do the `-print0` on find -- thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Given your latest edit I'd like to point you at my comment above again:

> Since you mention "same server": Is there any chance that special files like /proc/kcore or /dev/zero are anywhere in the path? That would certainly stop grep from going any further.....

Since adding an extension produces different results from the run w/o that kind of rules spaces as the culprit out.

Comment: that's a valid comment and I tried to answer it with `I realize I wasn't specific on the path, but these are all well-named directories, not to be confused with any devices`.  It's still possible that a malformed filename with spaces could have split oddly - I'll have to check when I have a little more time; however I doubt it.  I typically don't use spaces in Linux.  I think in looking at the "errors" the stopping point was at different places, but like I said... I will check because I hate not knowing the cause of problems to prevent them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -r something_to_find 2>/dev/null
```

"grep -r ..." will search all files recursively from $PWD.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | tee /tmp/file-list | xargs -0 egrep whatever
```

Does /tmp/file-list (view it with something that doesn't mind nulls) contain your desired file(s)?  If no, it's a find problem.  If yes, it's an xargs matter.

I've intentionally not 2>'d away the errors.  They may be useful.